# Generate a PDF from a twig page with GoogleMap

Tags: php, google-maps, symfony, pdf

Here, I use knpsnappybundle to generate pdfs. I want to generate a pdf of one of my pages HTML.twig. Everything goes well except GoogleMap. My pdf is created well as it should, all my data is provided without any problem except my googlemap. (of course my map appears well on HTML.twig)

I use ivory-google-map to generate my maps.

side Controller

```
$html = $this->renderView('TriangleClientBundle:Pdf:fiche_technique_acteur_pdf.html.twig',
            array(
     'map' => $map
                  ));
    //return new Response($html);

    return new Response(
    $this->get('knp_snappy.pdf')->getOutputFromHtml($html),
    200,
    array(
    'Content-Type'          => 'application/pdf',
    'Content-Disposition'   => 'attachment; filename="fiche_technique '.$nom.'.pdf"'
    )
    );`
```

Side html.twig

```
{{ google_map(map) }}
```

Comment: For the pdf, you could download the map as a static image like that:

`<img src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=<?php echo $latlong; ?>&zoom=14&size=900x300&markers=<?php echo $latlong; ?>&sensor=false" width="600px">` See here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/staticmaps/

Comment: yes but i generate my map with many markers, circle around the markers, polygon etc...

Answer (score 0):

Snappy pdf is grabbing html then renders it in pdf, but it doesn't interpret javascript.

You will have to use a [phantom.js](http://phantomjs.org/) or something like this to compute javascript, then render the resutling html in pdf.

Comment: thanks you for the response.but I also use "Highcharts-bundle" to generate graphics. And when I generate the PDF, there are graphs that are in the html.twig 

they are in this form (int the twig) 
<script type="text/javascript"> 
     {{Chart (barchart2)}} 
</ script>